# sqlalchemy Lambda module import error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, aws-lambda, flask-sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I am trying to connect my redshift database from AWS Lambda function. I am getting below error when I try to achieve the connection.

**Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'sqlalchemy'**

Below is the import code that I am using in my lambda. I have tried all possible import function. Still noting works. Results in the same error.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy as sa

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
```

Comment: `sqlalchemy` is not preinstalled on lambda so you have to include it in your deployment package: [See docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As 'sqlalchemy' is not a part of AWS SDK you should include it in your deployment package. If you are deploying it as a .zip file then make sure you have included it in the zip

Answer (score 0):

Put this lib in a Layer and import in your code, maybe this solve your problem.
Like Vijayanath Viswanathan saw, build a layer with .zip file.